# Three table join with a rand ()

Tags: php, sql, database, random

I'm trying to connect a select random to display information from tables 'tracks', 'albums'

```
select tracks, albums, artists, track.title, artist.name, album.title
From albums, tracks , artists
where albums.artistID = tracks.artistID;
and albums.artistID = artists.ID;
```

I'm not sure why it won't work and I'm trying to understand why, any help would be appreciated

Here is the piece of coding for the random, I'm unsure how to connect this with the 5 generated songs, along with their information displayed.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO songsoftheweek
            SELECT * FROM tracks
            ORDER BY RAND() 
            LIMIT 5"; 
$dbResult=mysql_query($query,$db);
```

Comment: try this:

select tracks, albums, artists, track.title, artist.name, album.title
From albums, tracks , artists
where albums.artistID = tracks.artistID;
and albums.artistID = artists.ID
order by newid()

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: PHPmyadmin is the database I'm using

Answer (score 0):

For starters, this is one problem: `select tracks, albums, artists`. The `select` statement is for identifying the *columns* you want to select. The `from` statement is for identifying tables...

There may be other things going on here... for instance, I don't see anything that looks at all like it's introducing randomness. Where is that supposed to be happening? But at least this should help solve one problem.

Comment: sorry my misttake - here is the piece of code I've used for the Random.

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO songsoftheweek
    SELECT * FROM tracks
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 5"; 
 $dbResult=mysql_query($query,$db);

Answer (score 0):

Give each track an ID field. Make a query which selects all fields from album, make which counts the rows.. and then put a rand() function behind that, example:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM DATABASE;");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$random = rand(1,$count);
$trackquery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE ID = $random;");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($trackquery))
{
 // do stuff
}
```